# CSS link:hover style only applies to the first instance even with using class

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, visited

I have been stuck on this thing for a while and was not able to come up with a solution. I have a few links that I have styled using class. However, it seems that the :hover and :visited state styling only applies to the first link, even though I specifically used class in order to style all of them. I really am not sure where the hold up is.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 push-md-3 max-auto main animsition">
    <h3 class="text-center">Contact <span class="dev">Me</span></h3>
    <p class="contactLinks"><a href="mailto:#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> - Email me</a></p>
    <p class="contactLinks"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> - Facebook</a></p>
    <p class="contactLinks"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> - Twitter</a></p>
    <p class="contactLinks"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> - LinkedIn</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main > h3 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.contactLinks a {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #262626; 
}

.contactLinks a:hover {
  color: #6E8A71;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.contactLinks a:visited {
  color: #262626;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `:hover` after the `:visited` event. And you can also add `.contactLinks a:visited:hover` so you are sure that when hovering over a visited link you get the desired result

As you know, you cannot set `text-decoration` on `:visited` links. It has to do with browser history security reasons. see here > [Privacy visited links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

You can instead use `border-bottom` to simulate the underline. See updated snippet below

```css
.main > h3 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.contactLinks a {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #262626; 
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}



.contactLinks a:visited {
  color: #262626;
  border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
  
}

.contactLinks a:hover,.contactLinks a:visited:hover{
  color: #6E8A71;
  border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 push-md-3 max-auto main animsition">
    <h3 class="text-center">Contact <span class="dev">Me</span></h3>
    <p class="contactLinks"><a href="mailto:#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> - Email me</a></p>
    <p class="contactLinks"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> - Facebook</a></p>
    <p class="contactLinks"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> - Twitter</a></p>
    <p class="contactLinks"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> - LinkedIn</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response! This fixes the :hover part but I'm still getting underlined links after I click them. Just now I'm reading that you cannot actually use text-decoration property on :visited links.Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: @TommyVee added a workaround for that issue. Read my edited answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your codes into codepen, and it seems to work just fine.
Are you trying this at a localhost or a server?
Did you tried cleaning your cache?

Comment: @tommyvee yupp it's working successfully in the online editors without any chnages

Comment: this isn't the way you give answer here. wait until you get credit so you can comment or else provide proper answer

Comment: I'm trying this on local. I got the hover part to work but I still cannot get rid of the underlining on visited links :/

Answer (score -3):

It's because of "href="#"". Change it to "href = "#something""